# Strange part in power supply

Tags: power-supply, identification

[image]

While examining a desktop computer power supply, I came across a strange part. I was curious and opened it, an ordinary short-circuited cable, what is the function of this part? It says EC on the circuit board. What is EC abbreviation?

**[More picture...](https://www.anandtech.com/Gallery/Album/312#2)**

Comment: I don't see any short-circuited cables or anything that says "EC" in any of your pictures. Which part are you talking about, exactly? Can you describe its appearance, including what color it is and where it is in the picture?

Comment: Whoa! Been some time since I’ve seen a _fake_ passive PFC choke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about the large (and, no doubt, heavy) magnetic device with the laminations, that's a *passive* power-factor correction choke.

In your other photo is what it is supposed to look like:

[image]

The current top photo shows a *fake* power-factor correction choke which was apparently found in some power supplies.

It's just a short and has no effect on the poor power factor of such supplies.

Comment: Actually, this is a *fake* power factor correction choke: A plastic case filled with metal scrap that looks like a PFC choke from the outside but doesn't actually contain any windings. This is common in super-cheap PSUs that pretend to have PFC but actually don't (which is illegal). It's also an indicator that the PSU is absolute garbage and may explode at any moment. (At least the one on the picture that's embedded in the question)

Comment: @JonathanS. The "More picture..." link in the question says it is an FSP PSU, and FSP are a reasonable manufacturer - they are an OEM for Antec, Cooler Master, EVGA, and more. Of course, it might not be a genuine FSP unit.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I agree. The PFC choke shown in the "More picture..." link looks genuine, the one on the embedded picture is 100% fake. They're not the same power supply, though - the PFC choke's wires have different colors and its connector is in a different place on the PCB.

Comment: @JonathanS. Thanks, I thought my eyes were playing tricks on me when I tried to reconcile the pictures.

Comment: Okay, the photo has changed drastically. The original was a very nice looking genuine choke.

Comment: I will confirm if you correct your answer. @SpehroPefhany

Comment: While I was researching what it was, I came across a similar one on the internet and quickly posted that picture :) @SpehroPefhany

Comment: @Jundullah Useful to see the two together I think.